# Symmetries of eigenfunctions of Sturm-Liouville

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetry, sturm-liouville

Let $p,q :(-1,1) \mapsto \mathbb{C}$. Assume the symmetry property $p(-x) = \overline{p(x)}$ and $q(-x) = \overline{q(x)}$ for $x \in (-1,1)$. Consider the Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem

$$(pu')' + qu = \lambda u \\ \lim_{x \to \pm1} p u' =0$$

Assume also that the eigenvalues $\lambda$ are only real. When can we say that $u$ would also satisfy the same symmetry property as the coefficients?

Comment: Do you have an example where $u$ doesn't satisfy the same symmetry property? I believe the answer is always.

Comment: Not really, however I don't see how to prove that $u$ should satisfy the symmetry.